# _ (underline) em consulta com LIKE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Estou fazendo uma consulta onde preciso retornar todas as informações de determinada tabela, que contém "**_R_**" na nomenclatura.

Porém, ao utilizar `WHERE NM_CAMPAIGN LIKE '%_R_%'` ele me retorna até outros casos que tem somente "**R_**".

De que outra forma eu consigo utilizar esse critério?

Comment: Qual o seu `SGBD`?

Comment: Isso porquê o caractere `_` também é um caractere coringa do SQL. Se você precisa dele literal, você precisa escapá-lo.

Comment: Utilizo o SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Reforçando para futuros leitores:[(Curinga – corresponde a um caractere) (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-match-one-character-transact-sql)

Comment: @Marconi coloquei essa referência na resposta

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Caso seu `SGBD` seja o `SQL Server` você precisa escapar o caractere:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE t.NM_CAMPAIGN LIKE '%[_]R[_]%'
```

---

> [`LIKE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
>
> Determina se uma cadeia de caracteres específica corresponde a um padrão especificado. Um padrão pode incluir caracteres normais e curingas. Durante a correspondência de padrões, os caracteres normais devem corresponder exatamente aos caracteres especificados na cadeia de caracteres. No entanto, os caracteres curinga podem ser correspondidos a fragmentos arbitrários da cadeia de caracteres. O uso de caracteres curinga torna o operador `LIKE` mais flexível que o uso dos operadores de comparação de cadeias de caracteres `=` e `!=`. Se qualquer um dos argumentos não for do tipo de dados de cadeia de caracteres, Mecanismo de Banco de Dados do `SQL Server` o converterá no tipo de dados de cadeia de caracteres, se for possível.

---

> [`_` (curinga – corresponde a um caractere)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/wildcard-match-one-character-transact-sql)
>
> Use o caractere sublinhado _ para corresponder a qualquer caractere único em uma operação de comparação de cadeia de caracteres que envolva correspondência de padrões, como `LIKE` e `PATINDEX`.

---

No caso do `LIKE` quando você utiliza o caractere `_` está especificando a ocorrência de um caractere qualquer, ou seja, para a instrução `%_R_%` você está especificando que quer qualquer resultado que:

- Possua `0` ou mais caracteres no início;
- Seja seguido por uma ocorrência de **qualquer caractere**;
- Possua a letra `R`;
- Tenha qualquer caractere seguido de qualquer coisa no final;

No seu caso vou listar alguns resultados possíveis:

```
- 0R0;
- 000R0;
- 000R000;
- 0_R_0;
```

Resultados que não seriam filtrados por sua busca:

```
- R0;
- 0R;
- R000;
- 000R;
- A;
- R;
```

É por isso que os resultados com `_R_` eram filtrados, já que obedecem a regra, mas não são os únicos que coincidem com o que foi especificado.

Comment: Isso funciona dessa forma em Oracle e MySql também ;)

Comment: @Renan obrigado pelo `feedback`. Irei incluir na resposta!

Comment: Por um momento eu pensei ter visto que você estava escapando o caractere com barra invertida. A barra funciona em todos os SGBD's. Os colchetes eu não tenho certeza =\

Comment: @Renan hehehe tranquilo, vou alterar a resposta novamente

Comment: @Sorack consegui! Obrigado

Comment: O responsável pelo `downvote` poderia dizer qual o problema que deve ser corrigido nesta resposta que justifica essa votação?

Answer (score 11):

O *underline* tem um significado parecido com o sinal de porcentagem na condição `LIKE` do SQL. Ambos são caracteres coringas.

A diferença é a seguinte:

- **%** procura por *zero ou mais* ocorrências de um caractere qualquer;
- **_** procura por *uma ou mais* ocorrências de um caractere qualquer.

Por exemplo, supondo que temos uma tabela com uma coluna chamada *palavra*, e que a tabela tem as seguintes palavras cadastradas:

> acata, categoria, catraca, escatologia, mercator

Então os resultados das consultas serão os seguintes

```
... where PALAVRA like '%cat%'
-- retorna acata, categoria, catraca, escatologia, mercator

... where PALAVRA like '_cat_'
-- retorna acata

-- Combinando os dois agora:
... where PALAVRA like '%_cat_%'
-- retorna acata, escatologia, mercator
```

---

Para procurar pelos caracteres coringa propriamente ditos, você deve escapá-los com uma barra invertida. Sua cláusula where deveria ficar assim:

```
... where NM_CAMPAIGN like '%\_R\_%'
```

Isso vale para os três principais SGBD's: SQL Server, Oracle e MySql.

Comment: Isso, perfeito. Dar a solução é legal, explicar o porquê do problema é muito melhor.

Comment: Já deixo meu +1, mas não conseguir compreender a diferença entre `%` e `_`na prática. Pode adicionar um exemplo @Renan?

Comment: @Marconi um minuto que eu coloco

Comment: @Renan, o caractere `_` procura por apenas um caractere, não?

Comment: @Marconi o `_` na realidade obriga uma quantidade de caracteres, então na realidade quando você coloca `_R` você diz que quer tudo que tenha 2 caracteres e termine em `R`. No caso dele apenas obriga que tenha 1 ou mais caracteres

Comment: @Sorack não quer incluir um Fiddle na sua resposta? Já deixei meu +1 lá também. Creio que um exemplo facilita o entendimento.

Comment: @Marconi vou incluir alguns exemplos, pode ser?

Comment: @Sorack Claro que sim :)

Comment: @Marconi eu não entendi, e o Fiddle só confirma o que eu falei no post.

Comment: @Marconi sugiro verificar no fiddle que `"_x_"` e `%_x_%` são equivalentes. Se ainda assim notar algo que não eu não vi aqui, você pode colocar sua própria resposta (com Fiddle). Eu sinceramente ainda não percebi a diferença.

Comment: @Marconi ah, agora caiu a ficha. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Já passei por isso, tirei minha solução [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18528852/4551469).

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(post_code_field, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(?, ' ', ''))
```